# Метод onConfigurationChanged не используется в приложении

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть проблемы с переводом tabbar вместе со фрагментами в приложении. На данный момент у меня переводится только содержимое fragment'ов(при смене языков в настройках).
Поясню, у меня в tabbar'e помимо иконок, есть имена фрагментов, по нажатию на которые я перехожу по фрагментам. Но при смене языка в приложении, tabbar меняет язык **только** если я убью приложение и перезайду заново. Поэтому было бы неплохо обновлять tabbar не выходя из приложения.

Решил перерисовывать элементы активити, реализовав метод:

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    invalidate()
    Log.d("onConfigurationChanged", "onConfigurationChanged")
}
```

А также добавил параметр в `AndroidManifest.xml` для locale:

```
            android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
```

Но в логах метод по-прежнему не используется.

Comment: Что это за tabbar?

Comment: @pavlofff в смысле что это?)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в Вашем классе с TabBar'ом использовать следующий метод:

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    invalidate()
}
```

Надеюсь будет полезным.

Comment: К сожалению ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @Inkognito проверьте вызываете ли вы вообще данный метод(такое может быть из за большого обилия view'шек)